# Queries in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have the following insert statement in my app which work.
Before the insert I want to first check the database if the value name does not exist in the name column.
If it does not exists I want to continue with the insert, else display an error message.

How do I incorporate it into my existing statement below?

```
public void insert(HashMap<String, String> queryValues){

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    Cursor c = database.query("SELECT * FROM user_details where" + "name=?", new String[] {values.put("name") });

    if (c.getCount() > 0) {
        // don't do it
        return;
    }


 else {
    values.put("name", queryValues.get("name"));
    values.put("age", queryValues.get("age"));

    database.insert("user", null, values);
    }
    database.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to add a `unique` constraint on the name field, and then use `insertWithOnConflict()` with a last argument of `CONFLICT_FAIL`. That's actually the default behavior. Your insert will fail if it would otherwise cause a constraint violation (`insert()` will return -1).

If you don't want to do that, there's no magic. Query your DB for a row with the given name field. If you are returned >0 rows, don't perform the insert.

```
Cursor c = db.query(..., "name=?", new String[] {theName}, ...);
if (c.getCount > 0) {
  // don't do it
  return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i have edited my code but something seems to be wrong with the select statement.

Comment: I didn't give the exact syntax for the select. Please refer to the Android SDK reference for details.